# brew install bash failing

Tags: bash, macos, homebrew

Trying to get a more recent version of bash installed on my Mac using brew.
brew is installed and working fine. When I try to run:
brew install bash
however I get the following error:

```
==> Downloading https://gist.githubusercontent.com/jacknagel/d886531fb6623b60b2a

curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found
Error: Failed to download resource "readline--patch"
Download failed: https://gist.githubusercontent.com/jacknagel/d886531fb6623b60b2af/raw/746fc543e56bc37a26ccf05d2946a45176b0894e/readline-6.3.8.diff
```

And indeed, there's nothing at:

```
https://gist.githubusercontent.com/jacknagel
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Update your Homebrew formulae and try again: `brew update`.